# Displaying a field as a comma separated list in Reporting Services 2005?

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

See title. Basically, the data in this report is set up such that each value in Field A has multiple corresponding values in Field B, and I need to display Field B as a comma-separated list. According to the internets, this is totally easy via a combination of Join() and LookupSet() in 2008... but I'm on 2005. Anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: This can be done but we need more information about the dataset structure. Tables, Fields, and the relationship between them.

Comment: It's fairly simple; there are three fields relevant to this issue. The part that I need to organize into a comma-separated list is a list of counties, and that's the third field. The first two are essentially state and region-within-state. So a sample might look like this:

State...Region.....County
ST......region 1...county 1
ST......region 1...county 2
ST......region 1...county 3
ST......region 2...county 4
ST......region 2...county 5


And so forth. So what I need is this:

State...Region.....County
ST......region1....county1, county2, county3

Anything I missed?

Comment: Ugh, sorry about the no line breaks. What. A. Noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Regional](
    [State] [char](20) NULL,
    [Region] [char](10) NULL,
    [County] [char](20) NULL
)
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT state,
       region,
       (SELECT Rtrim(county) + ','
        FROM   regional b
        WHERE  a.state = b.state
           AND a.region = b.region
        FOR XML PATH('')) counties,
       Count(*) countycount
FROM   regional a
GROUP  BY state,
          region
```

Here is the output:

```
state   region  counties                   countycount
AL      South   Mobile,Baldwin,           2
MS      South   Jackson,Harrison,Stone,   3
```

You will notice a trailing ',' that you will need to trim. That should be simple if your displaying this in SSRS.

Comment: Hey, thanks! That definitely looks like something I can work with.