# SQL select query - display related records in onr column

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, csv, pivot

I have these tables
[image: Tables]
I want to have a result like this

```
╭────────────┬────────────┬──────┬────────────────────────┬────────────────────────╮
│ InvoiceID  │    Date    │ Sum  │ SUM(RecietInvoice.Sum) │ RecietInvoice.RecietID │
├────────────┴────────────┴──────┴────────────────────────┴────────────────────────┤
│      1     │ 11/11/2010 │ 1200 │           1200         │        34,45           │
╰────────────┴────────────┴──────┴────────────────────────┴────────────────────────╯
```

In the RecietInvoice.RecietID I want to have all the RecietID for this Invoice.

Comment: Have a look at http://i.imgur.com/goWIq.png I want to have lines 29,30,31 as a single row with RecietID as "7,8,9"

Comment: If you need help with the comma separated list, try this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024456/displaying-a-field-as-a-comma-separated-list-in-reporting-services-2005

Comment: I'm wondering what the 10x means at the end.  (I'm thinking I get 10 times the number of interwebs.)

Comment: FYI, the word is spelled "Receipt", not "Reciet"

Comment: @JohnSaunders - That bugged me too - I had to make my spelling like his for the example.

Comment: Edit the title otherwise you'll be downvoted to oblivion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way (untested might have typos)

```
Select I.InvoiceID, I.Date, RI.Sum, 
   SUM(R.CashTotal) OVER(PARTITION BY  I.InvoiceID) 
     stuff( (SELECT ', '+CAST(RecietR2.RecietID as varchar(max))
             FROM  Reciet R2
             WHERE RecietR2.InvoiceID  = I.InvoiceID
             FOR XML PATH ('')
           ), 1, 2, '') as RecietIDs
FROM Invoice I
LEFT JOIN RecietInvoice RI ON I.InvoiceID = RI.InvoiceID
LEFT JOIN Reciet R ON RI.RecietID = R.RecietID
```

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.

Comment: Sounds like you have incorrect syntax... paste what you did (maybe pastebin is a good spot)

Comment: @Kulpemovitz Ok, I saw one typo, I did not have a cast.  I took out the order by because who cares?  Try this version.